# Webview Navigation causes freezing on winrt (non x86)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

When using webview.navigate(url), the entire app freezes up.  It's noticeable on x86 chips, but it completely freezes up tablets for close to 50 seconds.

I've tried many many things to try to marshall the thread, but absolutely nothing makes it better.

Any advice?

Here is the xaml and c#

```
<Page
    x:Class="WebviewSample.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:WebviewSample"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
            <ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="ListView_OnSelectionChanged">

            </ListView>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <WebView x:Name="webView"></WebView>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace WebviewSample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.  The Parameter
        /// property is typically used to configure the page.</param>
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            var itemsList = new List<ListViewItem>();
            for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++)
            {
                var listViewItem = new ListViewItem {Content = "Click Me!"};
                itemsList.Add(listViewItem);
            }
            listView.DataContext = itemsList;
        }

        private void ListView_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            webView.Navigate(new Uri("http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10001424127887324299104578529112289298922"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try to schedule Navigate call with Dispatcher and CoreDispatcherPriority.Low, but I don't think that this will solve your problem. It looks like you are trying to create webbrowser, just don't. Take a look on this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2012/10/18/nine-things-you-need-to-know-about-webview.aspx

Comment: This is just a sample app to show the issue.  I'm not trying to create a web browser, but I need to be able to display webpages.  Not all the time, but when necessary.  Besides, it also hangs when I use it to display generated html. but not as bad.